# CSV import is replacing < and > with _

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have the following code as part of a cron job

```
if (file_exists(DIR_FS_CATALOG . '/orderwise_imports/Zencart_Product_HTML_Info.csv')) {
$fileName = DIR_FS_CATALOG . '/orderwise_imports/Zencart_Product_HTML_Info.csv';
$file = fopen($fileName, "r");
fgetcsv($file, 0, ";", '|'); // read the first line and do nothing with it as we don't need to write the cell names to the database
while ( ($column = fgetcsv ( $file, 0, ';', '|' )) !== FALSE ) {
    $column = array_map(function ($string) {
        $string2 = zen_db_prepare_input($string);
        return str_replace("'", "\'", $string2);
    }, $column);
```

An example of one of the csv entries is

```
|2312|;|2312|;|EP-9SS-B-001|;|<p><strong>NINE bars deliver 9 great vitamin and mineral benefits for physical and mental energy in an easy to consume format, perfect for people on the go.</strong></p><p>Start your day the right way&hellip; this perfectly balanced NINE offers a healthy helping of satisfying oats and a tangy-sweet Berry flavour with the added staple of nutritious sunflower, pumpkin, sesame and hemp seeds for the perfect combination of Good Seeds and Great Tastes.</p><p><strong>USP:&nbsp; </strong>Made with natural seeds such as sunflower, pumpkin, sesame and chia.</p><p><strong>WOW FACT! </strong>Naturally vegan friendly range and poweredwith 100% plant protein.</p><p><strong>Lifestyle &amp; Dietary trends: </strong>Vegan; Source of Protein; Gluten Free.</p>|;|1459|
```

All the opening and closing html tags are being replaced with underscores. If I do

```
print_r($column);
```

I am seeing

```
Array ( [0] => 2312 [1] => 2312 [2] => EP-9SS-B-001 [3] => _p__strong_NINE bars deliver 9 great vitamin and mineral benefits for physical and mental energy in an easy to consume format, perfect for people on the go._/strong__/p__p_Start your day the right way… this perfectly balanced NINE offers a healthy helping of satisfying oats and a tangy-sweet Berry flavour with the added staple of nutritious sunflower, pumpkin, sesame and hemp seeds for the perfect combination of Good Seeds and Great Tastes._/p__p__strong_USP:  _/strong_Made with natural seeds such as sunflower, pumpkin, sesame and chia._/p__p__strong_WOW FACT! _/strong_Naturally vegan friendly range and poweredwith 100% plant protein._/p__p__strong_Lifestyle & Dietary trends: _/strong_Vegan; Source of Protein; Gluten Free._/p_ [4] => 1459 )
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. Anyone come across this before, and how did you resolve it?

Comment: `zen_db_prepare_input` looks like the only place where a translation might occur to me.

Comment: I agree with Scuzzy, but when I looked up the method in Zend it doesn't do any stripping of HTML - https://github.com/ZenMagick/ZenCart/blob/master/zc_admin/includes/functions/database.php#L68 - When you print out column before the array_map do you have the < >?

Comment: @blupointmedia Yes, I do.

Comment: @blupointmedia I downloaded a version `1.5.6c` in which `includes/functions/functions_general.php` also defines a `zen_db_prepare_input` function which calls `zen_sanitize_string` which features `preg_replace("/[<>]/", '_', $string)`

Comment: Scuzzy, yes, I just saw that. Can you please post the link and line number for Steph3071 and anyone else that might run into this issue?

Comment: That git repo appears to be 7 years old, trying to locate something online now.

Comment: Scuzzy, it looks like that method was moved out of functions and into database. Similar to the link I posted earlier. https://github.com/zencart/zencart/blob/v157/includes/functions/database.php#L65 - There is no html strip tags in that method. This file was updated 3 months ago

Comment: @Steph3071, I guess my first question should have been the version of Zend you are using.

Comment: @blupointmedia Version 1.5.6a

Comment: @Steph3071, that is correct then - https://github.com/zencart/zencart/blob/v156/includes/functions/functions_general.php#L900 - it is being removed in the https://github.com/zencart/zencart/blob/v156/includes/functions/functions_general.php#L99

Comment: It does appear to be related to zen cart sanitizing the data. Not sure of the best (right)way forward here. I could create a new function that doesn't run the zen cart sanitize process, but that leaves the csv import process open to potential attack.

Comment: I would recommend update to 1.5.7 and then it won't be stripping your HTML chars. Ref the first link I shared above.

Comment: @bluepointmedia 1.5.7 isn't officially released yet. 1.5.6c is the current stable release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zen_db_prepare_input does that transition.
check this:
http://phpcrossref.com/xref/zencart/includes/functions/functions_general.php.html#zen_db_prepare_input
line 865 and line 105

Comment: Indeed it does. And yet the same function in admin doesn't sanitise. I've modified the cron controlled file so that it calls the admin based function instead of the store side function.